# how to get info about whether a query got benefit from a particular index? postgresql9.6

Tags: postgresql, logging, indexing, postgresql-9.6

I want to set `log_statement` for only select statements if possible, otherwise i will use `all` statement.

After that i want to list queries to get information about whether a particular query hasnt used a particular index. Because when i drop and recreate that particular index, i want to check later if a query hasnt got benefit from this particular index.

I guess `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` wouldnt help.
Is it possible to list queries to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [auto-explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) to save execution plan to logs.

Also take a look at [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) to select (rank) slow statements right in db catalog...